# LDAP - how to use attribute from objectclass:account and objectclass:inetOrgPerson?

Tags: openldap, user-management, pam-ldap

I have an openLDAP which I use for authenticating users to various servers, where each user can have access to a varying number of hosts. I am solving that requirement by using the "host" attribute, and a filter in the PAM config of the machines using the LDAP for authentication, as described e.g. in https://wiki.debian.org/LDAP/PAM )by using the query "(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=$username)(|(host=$hostname)(host=$fqdn)(host=\*)))" )

Now I also have the need to add an attribute for emails to the user entries, for which objectclass:inetOrgPerson seems to be the best fit.

However, I can't use both objectclass:account and objectclass:inetOrgPerson at the same time; I can use objectclass:posixAccount and objectclass:inetOrgPerson, as described e.g. in [Adding inetOrgPerson to account/posixAccount LDAP entries](https://serverfault.com/questions/86225/adding-inetorgperson-to-account-posixaccount-ldap-entries), but then I lose the "host" attribute.

Anyone having a suggestion how to solve this issue? Is "extensibleObject" the only way to go?

EDIT: In the end, I used extensibleObject for that; doesn't feel like the "correct" solution because it reduces the usefulness of schema checks, but it seems to have been the only reasonable way.

Comment: What service is being authenticated by pam? Is it only ssh?

Comment: yes ssh (and occasionally login in locally at the machine)

(extensibleObject seems to work fine in general for what I need ATM, but it seems a hack..)

Answer (score 0):

If it's strictly ssh you could use `AllowGroups` and/or its kin in `ssh_config`. (Note: rfc2703bis schema allows for inheritance in groups, at least with `sssd`, rfc2703 aka nis schema does not.)

Otherwise, use `extensibleObject`, or you could write your own schema either to AUX host or SUP to posixAccount.

You could also restrict responses using OpenLDAP's [access control](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/access-control.html#Access%20Control%20via%20Dynamic%20Configuration), but I'm not getting into the details of that.